# Vector spaces over subfields

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given that $V$ is a vector space over $L$ with dimension $d$, and told that for a subfield $K \subset L$ we can view $V$ as a vector space over $K$. If we view $L$ as a vector space over $K$ with dimension $n$, I want to show that if we restrict $V$ to be a vector space over $K$ then it's dimension is $nd$.

I have no idea how to proceed. I doesn't make sense to me why the basis should be larger if we're restricting the field? Is there some intuitive reason why we should need more basis vectors? Thanks in advance for any hints/ clarifications.

Comment: Take for example $\mathbb{C}$. $\mathbb{C}$ is a $1$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ with basis $1$. Now $\mathbb{C}$ is a $2$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with basis $1,i$.

Comment: Do you mean $F$ (not $L$) is a vector space over $K$ with dimension $n$?

Comment: Take a basis $\{\,v_1,\dots,v_d\,\}$ for $V$ over $F$. Take a basis $\{\,f_1,\dots,f_n\,\}$ for $F$ over $K$. Consider the set of all $f_iv_j$.

Comment: You're right sorry @GerryMyerson I've edited it. But w.r.t your answer, I still don't understand. I get that $f_iv_j$ is going to have $nd$ elements but I can't really piece it together in my mind, what does one of the $\{f_1v_1,f_1v_2,...f_1v_d\}$ represent?

Comment: If $K \subset L$, and $V$ is an $L$-vector space with basis $v_1, \dots, v_d$, then $\sum Kv_i \subset V$ is strict (assuming $K \subset L$ is). You need more basis elements to fill in all the gaps. On a more conceptual level, if $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces(over any field), then $\dim V \otimes W = \dim(V)\dim(W)$. We may then apply this to the canonical identification $F^n = F \otimes_K K^n$.

Comment: Don't try to piece it together in your mind; piece it together on paper. You want to prove the set spans, and is linearly independent. There are standard ways – you've surely seen them – for proving a set spans a space, and for proving a set is linearly independent. Apply those methods to the set I gave. Write it all out, what it means for that set to span, and what it means for that set to be linearly independent, and then work through the proofs.

Comment: Making any progress?

Comment: Not yet but hopefully soon! I've been doing analysis to take a break @GerryMyerson